# How do I apply Stokes theorem on non contactable domain

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals

Vector field is given by and I need to find line integral of G on the line defined as the intersection of $x+y+z=2$ and $x^2+y^2=z$.

I know how to do this in general case when vector field is continuously differentiable on the region that curve bounds.
However this region is not contractile so I can’t apply Stokes theorem immediately.

Any idea what can be good approach in solving this kind of problems?
[image]

Comment: What's the usual technique for handling this issue in the plane? How do you apply Green's/Stokes's Theorem to, say, $\vec F = \left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)$ to integrate around an arbitrary simple closed curve enclosing the origin?

Comment: You take smooth surface enclosed by that curve and compute surface integral of (curlG,n), but since field is not integrale around origin we can’t do that

Comment: Did you answer my question? Green's/Stokes's Theorem does not apply if you include the origin in the region.